# SwiftUI Popover Attachment Anchor Offset From Trailing Edge

Tags: swift, swiftui

## Context:

In SwiftUI on macOS 12.0, I'm showing a Popover like this:

[image]

```
Button {
   isShowingFilterPopover.toggle()
} label: {
   ...
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)
.popover(isPresented: $isShowingFilterPopover, attachmentAnchor: .point(.bottomTrailing), arrowEdge: .bottom, content: { ... })
```

## Question:

I would like to tell SwiftUI to anchor this popover 8 points to the left of the button's `.bottomTrailing` location.

I know that I can specify an exact point as an offset from the button, like this:

```
attachmentAnchor: .rect(.rect(CGRect(x: 70, y: 15, width: 0, height: 0)))
```

But that works from the *leading* (left) edge button's frame and I need to work from its *trailing* (right) edge. Reason: the button's text ("All Entries") dynamically changes to show whatever search term the user enters, which means the *width* of the button changes. Working from the leading edge with a constant offset is therefore not possible.

So, how do I tell SwiftUI to anchor the popover 8 points to the left of the button's trailing edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give a 8px smaller view for popover, and everything else will happen automatically.

Here is a demo. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4

[image: demo]

```
Button { self.isPop.toggle() }
    label: { Text("Pop").padding() }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
    .padding(.horizontal, -8)          // << here !!
    .popover(isPresented: $isPop,
             attachmentAnchor: .point(.bottomTrailing),
             arrowEdge: .bottom) { ... }
    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOS/Findings/TestOffsetPopoverAnchor.swift)

Comment: Brilliant! I had to add the padding back after the popover or the button itself shifted to the right 8 points when no border is drawn on it. I've edited to add that final line. Thanks!